# What is the Right Way to Implement a Responsive Splash Screen in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, splash-screen, react-navigation-v5

I need to setup a splash screen that will scale responsively on all native devices like ios, android phones, tablet etc. The splash screen contains the following:

- Text Logo name
- Activity Indicator https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator

I can see that this guide is among the top search result [react-native-splash-screen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen), but not sure if it scales well on all native devices phone & tablets.

Should I just make a custom screen component and apply [react-native-responsive-screen](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen)?

Is there a convention/best practice on setting up the splash screen on react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support responsive splash screen or bootsplash, you need add images in differents resolutions, [example in Android](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities): mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi,... I currently use [react-native-boot-splash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash) it its other option to react-native-splash-screen, this package have a cli tool `npx generate-bootsplash` to generate bootsplash in differents resolutions in both platforms.

Other hand to add ActivityIndicator only check the [example](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/blob/master/example/App.js) and put ActivityIndicator component below bootsplash wrapped with Animated.Image

Comment: Its advisable to go with react-native-boot-splash ?